# How do I allow PHP to use curl?

Tags: php, curl, include-path

When I try to use the program `/usr/bin/curl` from within PHP I get the error

> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/bin/curl) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/share/php/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/) in /var/www/check.inc.php on line 138

How can i enable this on debian wheezy with PHP 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked by adding the path to curl to the [ini.include-path](https://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.include-path):

I added this line in my apache config for this site:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/usr/share/php/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/bin/curl"
```